# Graphing $r^3cos(3\theta)-1=0$ in the $xy$ plane.

Tags: polar-coordinates

Graphing $r^3cos(3\theta)-1=0$ in the $xy$ plane.

How would I go about doing this? By computers I know that it looks like three hyperbola's. How could I see this without the help of a computer? Would the best way just be to plug in nice values for $\theta$ and solve for $r$ and get points until i can figure out what the graph looks like?

Comment: I'd solve for $r$ then see what happens as I change $\theta$. Note that the cube root function is bijective so the function will be well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us consider searching for when asymptotes occur, that is, when $r \rightarrow \infty$. Rearranging, we see this is equivalent to when $\frac{1}{\cos(3\theta)} \rightarrow \infty$.

This occurs at the roots of $\cos(3\theta)$, which in the domain $[0,2\pi]$ are given by $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{6}, \frac{7\pi}{6}, \frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{11\pi}{6}$.

Hence, we may sketch out our asymptotes at these angles, which in Cartesian form are   given by $y = x\tan{\theta_0}$ for the above $\theta_0$ (e.g. $y = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$)

Furthermore, we note that $r > 0$, so our curve can only exist in alternating regions between each asymptote.

Finally, we can consider searching for local minima of $r$, which occur for $3\theta = 2\pi n$, so we have minima at $\theta = 0,\frac{2\pi}{3},  \frac{4\pi}{3}$ where $r = 1$.

This gives you a set of key points, which together with the asymptotes, should enable you to recover the three 'quasi-hyperbolae' on pen and paper.

Comment: Enjoyable answer!

Comment: "Furthermore, we note that $r > 0$, so our curve can only exist in alternating regions between each asymptote. "

Can you explain this to me? Great answer btw!

Comment: Essentially, $r$ describes the distance from the origin, and distance must be a positive number. When $cos(\theta) = 0$ (at an asymptote) it subsequently switches sign from positive to negative (its graph oscillates between each sign). Thus, $r = \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)^{1/3}}$ is not defined until the next root is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite

$$\cos(3 \theta) = \cos^3(\theta) - 3 \cos(\theta) \sin^2(\theta)$$

Recall that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, $x = r \cos(\theta)$, and $y = r\sin(\theta)$.

So, your original equation can be expressed in rectangular coordinates as:

$$(x^2 + y^2)^3 \frac{x^3 - 3xy^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^3} - 1 = 0 $$

Solving for $y$, we have:

$$y^2 = \frac{x^3 - 1}{3x} = \frac{x^2}{3} - \frac{1}{3x}$$

This last representation can let you see where the various asymptotes are, which may help you "see... that it looks like three hyperbolas." You can find it graphed [**here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ybb0eqybjv) or illustrated in the screenshot of this graph below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Prior knowledge of conics and polar curves would be useful to target this question, such as general shapes; e.g. rose curves, lemniscates etc. See [Polar Curves On Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/polar-curves/).

The equation $r = \sec^{1/3}{3\theta}$ is an **epispiral**, since its inverse $r = \cos^{1/3}{3\theta}$ is equivalent of an odd rose curve. If we first analyse and draw the given rose curve above, it is not difficult to draw out the inverse.

> Minima w.r.t to the radius

The rose curve $r = \cos^{1/3}{3\theta}$ has maximum radial points at $r = 1$, since $\max(\cos^{1/3}{n\theta}) = 1^{1/3} = 1$. Since, there are $n = 3$ petals, there are $3$ angles and they are **evenly** spread along the angular plane. $\cos({\theta = 0}) = 1$ being the first and a difference between each angle of $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$, the other two would be $\theta = \dfrac{2\pi}{3}, \dfrac{4\pi}{3}$. Note that $r = 1$, hence the epispiral and the rose curve **touch** at these 3 angles, and this would its radial minima. We can figure out the $xy$ equivalent, using the parametric transformation $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$. These would respectively be, $(x, y) = (1, 0), (-\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}), (-\dfrac{1}{2}, -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

> Asymptotes

Asymptotes will occur when the rose curve, $\cos{3\theta} = 0 \implies \dfrac{1}{\cos{3\theta}} \to \dfrac{1}{0} \to \infty$. Therefore, $\cos{3\theta} = 0$ over $[0, 2\pi]$ yields $6$ solutions; $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{6}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{5\pi}{6}, \dfrac{7\pi}{6}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}, \dfrac{11\pi}{6}$. Since, $\theta$ represents the angle of made between the asymptote and the $x-$axis, we can figure out the cartesian equation of the asymptotes using $y = x \cdot \tan{\theta}$. These would respectively be $x = 0, y = \pm\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$.

This is all we require to draw the epispiral. It can be done as shown below:

[image: Graph]

Note the inclusion of the purple dotted circle. If one were to generalise the graph $r = a\sec^{1/3}{n\theta}$, notice that it always greater than the minimum circle bounding its rose inverse; $r^{-1} = a\cos^{1/3}{n\theta}$, since the two curves only meet at the roses' maximum radius. Hence, all we require then is the asymptotes and the minimum bounding circle $r = a$:

[image: Graph 2]